# List items unwanted spanning the area?

Tags: html, css

might be a stupid simple solution but I can't seem to find what's wrong here:

*Simple setting*: one `<div>` container with two contents: one `<ul>` list on the left and another `<div>` right beside it.

**Problem**: Somehow the `<li>` items got something like a `margin-right:auto;`. I have not declared it that way anywhere, even with margin:0!important; there is no change. This behaviour makes the right container move under the list block. Because of a picky but required js, I cannot use css floating.

This is the code:

```
<div class="full">
    <div class="text_container" stlye="position:relative;width:250px;">
        <ul>
        <li class="box_link2">Item 1</li>
        <li class="box_link2">Item 2</li>
        <li class="box_link2">more items</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="text_container">
        <p>Content</p>      
    </div>
</div>
```

I just don't get why the list item can't be controlled. Is it normal that way? Even if I change the order of the two content `div`s I still can't click or select text on the right one because of the `li`'s expansion.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that you spelt it `'stlye'`?

Comment: Even with style spelt right I doubt the width would be correct - someone correct me if I am wrong but I don't think you can set the width of a relative div. You should set the position to absolute or fixed for this, I believe.

Comment: **@Jeriko** Now that you tell me, I am. Silly me. Does not change a thing though. Thanks.

Comment: **@ClarkeyBoy** It worked me for me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here : http://www.jsfiddle.net/9V2eH/

Because you can't use `float`, you'll need `display:inline-block`.

Also, you'll need to precise a width for your `div`.

Be aware that you may need to precise an `overflow:hidden` on your `div`  containing the `ul` to prevent any text overflow from them.

Comment: Thank you Chouchenos. Ported to my exact code, it still does not work though. Now the LIs and UL does not overflow anymore but the div that contains them spreads over the full width (using Safaris & Firefox' debug console). The widths should be correct (.full=880px, ul-div=250, content-div=500, margins&paddings minimal)

Comment: _It works now!_ Seems as if position:relative is a bad idea in this case. Had it in the .text_container class. I am relieved, thank you man! Appreciated!

Comment: @neoflox : Well, yeah, obiously I removed the `position:relative` since it didn't have any purpose here. Happy you worked it out by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal block behavior.

Are you floating the `.text_container` to the left ? If not, then nothing is wrong. If yes then a little more info is required like the widths of the `.text_container` and the width of the `.full`.

Comment: No I don't float anything. The .full and .text_container only define a few pixels of margin&padding and position:relative, which is neglectedable.

Comment: Quite simple: `position:relative` was needless here for once. And I forget to `clear:both` properly. That cause the divs false position.

Comment: I see. It makes sense... Next time though post the CSS as well ;) Glad you got it worked out.